# Image Upload in a Custom Module

Tags: 7, forms, files

I'm writing a custom module, and I need it to upload an image. I'm having trouble finding good documentation on this, but I think I'm close.

What am I missing? $file returns false in the form submission.

```
function mymodule_custom_content_block_form($form_state){
    $form = array();
    $form['custom_content_block_text'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => t('Block text'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('mymodule_custom_content_block_text'),
        '#required' => true,
    );
    $form['custom_content_block_image'] = array(
        '#type' => 'file',
        '#name' => 'custom_content_block_image',
        '#title' => t('Block image'),
        '#size' => 40,
        '#description' => t("Image should be less than 400 pixels wide and in JPG format."),
    );  
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Update'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function mymodule_custom_content_block_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    if(isset($form_state['values']['custom_content_block_image'])){
        $validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg jpeg'));
        $file = file_save_upload('custom_content_block_image', $validators, 'public://');
        if($file == false){
            drupal_set_message(t("Error saving image."), $type = "error", $repeat = false);
        }
        else{
            $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
            $file = file_save($file);   
        }
    }
    variable_set('mymodule_custom_content_block_text', $form_state['values']['custom_content_block_text']);
    drupal_set_message(t('Custom Content Block has been updated.'));
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't mind my saying you're doing this the hard way. Drupal has a [`managed_file`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) element type that handles most of this logic for you:

```
function mymodule_custom_content_block_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['custom_content_block_image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#name' => 'custom_content_block_image',
    '#title' => t('Block image'),
    '#size' => 40,
    '#description' => t("Image should be less than 400 pixels wide and in JPG format."),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://'
  ); 

  return $form; 
}

function mymodule_custom_content_block_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form_state['values']['custom_content_block_image'])) {
    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['custom_content_block_image']);

    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

    file_save($file);
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that file_save is only available after Drupal 6.

Answer (score 5):

With Clive answer my image got deleted after 6 hours. So if someone experienced the same problem that I got. Here is the solution (from Clive's answer with a little addition).

```
function mymodule_custom_content_block_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['custom_content_block_image'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#name' => 'custom_content_block_image',
    '#title' => t('Block image'),
    '#size' => 40,
    '#description' => t("Image should be less than 400 pixels wide and in JPG format."),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://'
  ); 

  return $form; 
}

function mymodule_custom_content_block_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form_state['values']['custom_content_block_image'])) {
    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['custom_content_block_image']);

    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

    $file_saved =file_save($file);
    // Record that the module is using the file. 
    file_usage_add($file_saved, 'mymodule_custom_content_block_form', 'custom_content_block_image', $file_saved->fid); 
  }
}
```

The solution is to add `file_usage_add`. From API documentation:

> Note: New files are uploaded with a status of 0 and are treated as temporary files which are removed after 6 hours via cron. Your module is responsible for changing the $file objects status to FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT and saving the new status to the database. Something like the following within your submit handler should do the trick.

See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#managed_file

Answer (score 1):

This attribute should be added to your form in order for it to work with file uploads.

```
$form['#attributes']['enctype'] = "multipart/form-data";
```