# Why is my file upload always NULL in $form_state?

Tags: forms, media, users, files

I've build a form where the user can upload an image as avatar for his profile. But I have an issue as the selected image is not being recognized at all.

I used the [image example from drupal.org](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/image_example!image_example.pages.inc/function/image_example_style_form/7), this is my minimal code not working at all:

```
function my_edit_form($form, $form_state, $entity) {

  $form['picture']['picture_upload'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t("Upload picture"),
    '#description' => t("Your virtual face or picture. Pictures larger than 150x150 pixels will be scaled down."),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://pictures/',
    '#size' => 48,
  );

  return $form;
}
```

[image: upload picture form]

Now, I'm trying to use the `file()` functions as described in the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/image_example!image_example.pages.inc/function/image_example_style_form_submit/7) but it seems my `$form_state['values']['picture']` is always `NULL`.

```
function my_edit_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form_state);
}
```

[image: devel form state values output]

I have no idea how that's possible and I'm a bit lost here. Any idea what else I could try?

Comment: I would recommend you use managed_file as form element instead, please see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25516/image-upload-in-a-custom-module for reference. As for your code it is the element picture_upload that will hold the actual value and not picture but I can't see now directly what's wrong, sorry :(

Comment: `#upload_location` is also only valid for `managed_file` elements...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, this is tricky how Drupal handles the file uploads and took me some time to figure out.

`$form_state` indeed shows NULL or empty strings or empty arrays for my file upload **unless I add a proper upload function**. The file exists but is not uploaded yet.

It's worth taking a look at [`user_validate_picture()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_validate_picture/7):

```
function user_validate_picture(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // If required, validate the uploaded picture.
  $validators = array(
    'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
    'file_validate_image_resolution' => array(variable_get('user_picture_dimensions', '85x85')),
    'file_validate_size' => array(variable_get('user_picture_file_size', '30') * 1024),
  );

  // Save the file as a temporary file.
  $file = file_save_upload('picture_upload', $validators);
  if ($file === FALSE) {
    form_set_error('picture_upload', t("Failed to upload the picture image; the %directory directory doesn't exist or is not writable.", array('%directory' => variable_get('user_picture_path', 'pictures'))));
  }
  elseif ($file !== NULL) {
    $form_state['values']['picture_upload'] = $file;
  }
}
```

Calling this function from inside my own validation function will upload the file to `temporary://What-is-Sustainability_0.png` and it's now visible in `$form_state['values']`:

[image: form state including picture]

This is what I was looking for, now I can simply save the file where I need it and have the `fid` available to link it to entities.

Answer (score 4):

For Drupal 8:

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){

    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);

    $validators = array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array("pdf"),
        'file_validate_size' => array(file_upload_max_size()),
    );

    // Save the file as a temporary file.
    $file = file_save_upload('field_upload', $validators, FALSE, 0, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
    if ($file === FALSE) {
        $form_state->setError($form["field_upload"], "Failed to upload the file");
    }
    elseif ($file !== NULL) {

        $form_state->setValue("field_upload", $file->toArray());
    }



}
```